# Form based authentication - Login get fails

Tags: sharepoint, moss, wss

I am using form based suthentication in my site. I have used one custom user control in my site which read items in sharepoint list and display it in a grid. Everything works fine with windows authentication but when I change the authentication to form based the login process get fails. I see the Error log it is giving me an error saying that

"An SPRequest object was not disposed before the end of this thread"

Then I have dispose all my spweb and spsite object that I have used in user control but still login process is not wotking.

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are having problems with your forms authentication configuration, please ask at Server Fault http://serverfault.com. This site is for programming questions. (By the way, the SPRequest messages are very unlikely to be related to your problems with forms authentication.)

Answer (score 0):

Try not disposing your SPSite object within your method.